# AWS Cloudfront only cache objects for only certain POST requests

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Can we use AWS Cloudfront and only cache the response for only certain requests

ie we only want to cache requests in Cloudfront for urls such as

POST [https://server.com/?q="sometext"](https://server.com/?q=%22sometext%22)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront can only cache the responses to request methods `GET` and `HEAD` (and, optionally, `OPTIONS`).

[CloudFront does not cache responses to requests that use other methods.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomHTTPMethods)

If your `?q=...` request is something idempotent, like a search query, consider using `GET` instead of `POST`, using `<form method="get" ...>` for example, if it's coming from a form.

Comment: Ah my mistake, yes the form in question does a GET request 
so is it possible to just cache these requests ?

Comment: @DavidU yes, take a look at [Cache Behavior Settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesCacheBehavior).  Cache behaviors match specific request path patterns (e.g. `/*` or `/api/*`) and determine the default handling for requests matching that pattern.  This is also where you can tell CloudFront which query string parameters to forward to the origin, and which to cache against.  CloudFront honors the `Cache-Control` response header, so your origin server can also participate in CloudFront caching decisions.